# How to print content of all (compressed, rolled over and current) Apache log files

Tags: bash

Apache produces log files (i.e. `httpd.log`). After a given time, log files are rolled over (i.e into `httpd.log-20210627`). When a log file is rolled over again, the previous rolled over version is compressed (i.e. into `httpd.log-20210620.gz`).

As root, I can list all these files.

```
[root@server user]# ls -latr /var/log/httpd/localhost/httpd.log*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9364779  6. Jun 03:48 /var/log/httpd/localhost/httpd.log-20210606.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  8407071 13. Jun 03:27 /var/log/httpd/localhost/httpd.log-20210613.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  7099637 20. Jun 03:35 /var/log/httpd/localhost/httpd.log-20210620.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 91551338 27. Jun 03:45 /var/log/httpd/localhost/httpd.log-20210627
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 49229622 30. Jun 17:28 /var/log/httpd/localhost/httpd.log
[root@server user]#
```

Using `bash`, I'd like to print the content of all log files, in temporal order, as an otherwise unprivileged user (that is: using `sudo`, not in a root shell), so I can, for example, grep through them.

Printing the content of the current log file is easy, because it has a fixed filename:

```
sudo cat /var/log/httpd/localhost/httpd.log
```

Printing the content of the compressed log files is almost as easy, because I can write a pattern that matches all relevant compressed files and use `zcat` to print the uncompressed content:

```
sudo su - -c "zcat /var/log/httpd/localhost/httpd.log-*.gz"
```

But so far I couldn't figure out how to print the content of the rolled over but not yet compressed log file. This is because I don't know the actual filename and a pattern like `/var/log/httpd/localhost/httpd.log*` will match all the compressed files as well.

According to [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html), I can make use of more complex patterns, when I enable `extglob`:

> If the `extglob` shell option is enabled using the `shopt` builtin, several extended pattern matching operators are recognized. []
>
> […]
>
> `+(pattern-list)`
>
> Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns.

According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/846987/882970) answer, I need to use a subshell, If I want to enable `extglob` in a single command. And indeed, this works as expected in a root shell. Executing `shopt -s extglob` and then `cat /var/log/httpd/localhost/httpd.log-+([0-9]) )` prints the content of the log file in question.

Outside of a root shell, however, I get an error:

```
[user@server ~]$ sudo su - -c "( shopt -s extglob ; cat /var/log/httpd/localhost/httpd.log-+([0-9]) )"
-bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: -c: line 0: `( shopt -s extglob ; cat /var/log/httpd/localhost/httpd.log-+([0-9]) )'
[user@server ~]$
```

This is the same error that I get when I try to execute `cat /var/log/httpd/localhost/httpd.log-+([0-9])` in the root shell without enabling `extglob`. I'm not sure why this doesn't work, because enabling `extglob` appears to be working in the given circumstances:

```
[user@server ~]$ sudo su - -c "( shopt -s extglob ; shopt extglob )"
extglob         on
[user@server ~]$
```

So I'd like to know how I can print the content of a file with an unknown filename outside of a root shell, when I need `extglob` to write the pattern. But this may be an [xy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)-problem, so my actual question is:

How can I print the content of all of Apache's log files outside of a root shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `zgrep`

You can use [`zgrep`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/zgrep-command-in-linux-with-examples/) to search a folder of both compressed and non-compressed logs.

The [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zgrep) writes about `zgrep`:

> Zgrep invokes grep on compressed or gzipped files. All options specified are passed directly to grep. If no file is specified, then the standard input is decompressed if necessary and fed to grep. Otherwise the given files are uncompressed if necessary and fed to grep.

I have tried re-creating your example with a current log, an older log and a compressed log:

```bsh
saaru >ls -o
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 ba 25 Jun 30 23:06 httpd.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 ba 66 Jun 30 23:07 httpd.log-20210530.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 ba 29 Jun 30 23:07 httpd.log-20210630
```

The contents of the files are as follows:

```bsh
saaru >cat httpd.log
This is the current log

saaru >cat httpd.log-20210630
This is the rolled over log

saaru >zcat httpd.log-20210530.gz
This is the compressed log.
```

With below command you can find the word "compressed" in the logs:

```bsh
saaru >zgrep "compressed" httpd.log*
httpd.log-20210530.gz:This is the compressed log.
```

Or find all log lines that do not have that word:

```bsh
saaru >zgrep -v "compressed" httpd.log*
httpd.log:This is the current log
httpd.log:
httpd.log-20210530.gz:
httpd.log-20210630:This is the rolled over log
httpd.log-20210630:
```

#### `zcat`

If you don't want to search, but simply `cat` all files you can use `zcat`  with the [`-f` flag](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=zcat+-f):

```bsh
saaru >zcat -f httpd.log*
This is the current log

This is the compressed log.

This is the rolled over log
```

#### Further reading

Here [is an article](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/05/zcat-zless-zgrep-zdiff-zcmp-zmore-gzip-file-operations-on-the-compressed-files/) on all the different `z*` commands.